# Can I flush my NHibernate session and get a new session without committing the transaction?

Tags: nhibernate, testing, castle-activerecord, database-testing

I'm using Castle ActiveRecord for persistence, and I'm trying to write a base class for my persistence tests which will do the following:

- Open a transaction for each test case and roll it back at the end of the test case, so that I get a clean DB for each test case without me having to rebuild the schema for each test case.
- Provide the ability to flush my NHibernate session and get a new one in the middle of a test, so that I know that my persistence operations have really hit the DB rather than just the NHibernate session.

In order to prove that my base class (`ARTestBase`) is working, I've come up with the following sample tests.

```
[TestFixture]
public class ARTestBaseTest : ARTestBase
{
    [Test]
    public void object_created_in_this_test_should_not_get_committed_to_db()
    {
        ActiveRecordMediator<Entity>.Save(new Entity {Name = "test"});

        Assert.That(ActiveRecordMediator<Entity>.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
    }

    [Test]
    public void object_created_in_previous_test_should_not_have_been_committed_to_db()
    {
        ActiveRecordMediator<Entity>.Save(new Entity {Name = "test"});

        Assert.That(ActiveRecordMediator<Entity>.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
    }

    [Test]
    public void calling_flush_should_make_nhibernate_retrieve_fresh_objects()
    {
        var savedEntity = new Entity {Name = "test"};
        ActiveRecordMediator<Entity>.Save(savedEntity);
        Flush();
        // Could use FindOne, but then this test would fail if the transactions aren't being rolled back
        foreach (var entity in ActiveRecordMediator<Entity>.FindAll())
        {
            Assert.That(entity, Is.Not.SameAs(savedEntity));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my best effort at the base class. It correctly implements `Flush()`, so the third test case passes. However it does not rollback the transactions, so the second test fails.

```
public class ARTestBase
{
    private SessionScope sessionScope;
    private TransactionScope transactionScope;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void InitialiseAR()
    {
        ActiveRecordStarter.ResetInitializationFlag();
        ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(typeof (Entity).Assembly, ActiveRecordSectionHandler.Instance);
        ActiveRecordStarter.CreateSchema();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public virtual void SetUp()
    {
        transactionScope = new TransactionScope(OnDispose.Rollback);
        sessionScope = new SessionScope();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public virtual void TearDown()
    {
        sessionScope.Dispose();
        transactionScope.Dispose();
    }

    protected void Flush()
    {
        sessionScope.Dispose();
        sessionScope = new SessionScope();
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public virtual void TestFixtureTearDown()
    {
        SQLiteProvider.ExplicitlyDestroyConnection();
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using a custom SQLite provider with an in-memory database. My custom provider, taken from [this blog post](http://brian.genisio.org/2008/07/active-record-mock-framework.html), keeps the connection open at all times to maintain the schema. Removing this and using a regular SQL Server database doesn't change the behaviour.

Is there a way to acheive the required behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure about ActiveRecord, but in NHibernate a transaction belongs to a session, not the otherway round.

If you've used ADO.Net a lot, this will make more sense, as to create an `IDbTransaction` you need to use the connection. ActiveRecord's `TransactionScope` (and NHibnerate's `ITransaction`)  essentially wrap an `IDbTransaction`, so you need to create the `SessionScope` before the `TransactionScope`.

What you might also find (depending on if you're using NHibernate 1.2 GA or NHibernate 2.*, and what `FlushMode` your `SessionScope` has) is that your call to `FindAll()` may cause the session to flush anyway, as NHibernate will realise that it can't retrieve the correct data without actioning the last call to `Save`.

This all said and done, have you tried using `SessionScope.Flush()` instead of creating a new `SessionScope`?

Answer (score 0):

Using `SessionScope.Flush()` makes my third test fail. As I understand it, `Flush()` executes the SQL to push my records into the DB, but does not evict objects from the session. That fits with what you say about `FindAll()` causing a flush.

What I really want is `SessionScope.Flush()` (to synchronise state of DB with session) plus `SessionScope.EvictAll()` (to ensure I get fresh objects in subsequent queries). My `new SessionScope()` was an attempt to simulate `EvictAll()`.

Your comments about the session enclosing the transaction rather than the other way round did give me an idea. I'm not sure how kosher it is to create a new `SessionScope` inside a  `TransactionScope` inside a flushed `SessionScope`, and expect it to participate in the transaction, but it seems to work:

```
public abstract class ARTestBase
{
    private SessionScope sessionScope;
    private TransactionScope transactionScope;
    private bool reverse;
    private IList<SessionScope> undisposedScopes;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void InitialiseAR()
    {
        ActiveRecordStarter.ResetInitializationFlag();
        ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(typeof (Entity).Assembly, ActiveRecordSectionHandler.Instance);
        ActiveRecordStarter.CreateSchema();
        InitialiseIoC();
        undisposedScopes = new List<SessionScope>();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public virtual void SetUp()
    {
        sessionScope = new SessionScope();
        transactionScope = new TransactionScope(OnDispose.Rollback);
        transactionScope.VoteRollBack();
        base.CreateInstanceUnderTest();
        reverse = false;
    }

    [TearDown]
    public virtual void TearDown()
    {
        if (reverse)
        {
            sessionScope.Dispose();
            transactionScope.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            transactionScope.Dispose();
            sessionScope.Dispose();
        }
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public virtual void TestFixtureTearDown()
    {
        foreach (var scope in undisposedScopes)
        {
            scope.Dispose();
        }
        SQLiteProvider.ExplicitlyDestroyConnection();
    }

    protected void Flush()
    {
        reverse = true;
        sessionScope.Flush();
        undisposedScopes.Add(sessionScope);
        sessionScope = new SessionScope();
    }
}
```

On further thought, this won't allow you to flush more than once in each test case. I think I can handle that by tracking the scopes more carefully. I might look into it later.